# Why is python 3 giving me "expected string or buffer"

Tags: python, regex

Trying out RegexMagic, I wanted to replace a bunch of characters in a file with null (i.e., delete them). I read in a file as a string.Then I apply a slightly modified version of the RegexMagic-generated regex expression, but I get  "expected string or buffer." It is a string because I can print it as a string and "in" works with it.

```
f = open('y:\\prepped.txt')
s = f.read().replace('\x1A','').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode('ascii')
s = re.sub(r"(?:®NT|¯+ _®MD\+SD|®MD-SD¯)","",re.DOTALL)
print(s)
```

It doesn't print, and I get the error message. This is Python 3.3.

Comment: You’re not even passing `s` to anything…?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't specify which string to modify. If you want to replace the pattern `"(?:®NT|¯+ _®MD\+SD|®MD-SD¯)"` with the replacement `""` within the string `s`, and specify a `re.DOTALL` flag, you can do:

```
s = re.sub(r"(?:®NT|¯+ _®MD\+SD|®MD-SD¯)", "", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The syntax for using re.sub is `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` For more information, see the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html